# Instance property in PreparingEventArgs?

Tags: instance, registration, autofac

According to the documentation, PreparingEventArgs should have an Instance property, so you can supply an alternative instance instead of the default.

But as far as I can see, that property isn't there. Is it supposed to be there or not?

(I know I can swap the instance in the activating event, but I want to avoid creating an instance if I'll just have to throw it away anyway.)

Answer (score 1):

What version of Autofac are you using?

In the latest source the `Instance` property is indeed removed. The alternative is to hook on to the [`Activating`](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/lifetime/events.html?highlight=ReplaceInstance) event and use the `ReplaceInstance` method on the `ActivatingEventArgs`.

Comment: The latest version, via NuGet.The problem is that when I use the Activating event, there's an instance created that I just have to throw away. That instance isn't exactly lightweight (it's a Windows Form), so I want to avoid creating them when they're not needed.

Comment: Actually, now that I'm thinking about it, the preparing event is the wrong place as well. Because when that gets at the component that I want to replace, all its dependencies will already have been created as well, which is also a waste of resources. I need to intercept the call as early as possible.

Comment: So are you saying that you will *always* create and replace the instance? If so, why not just register an action that builds the component. That way you have complete control over how the instance is built.

Comment: No, not all the time. It depends. The components I need to sometimes replace are created by a bunch of delegate factories. Instead of calling those factories directly, I think I'll have to use methods that check if there's a new instance needed or not, and only then use the delegate factories. It's a bit more work to code, but it'll work.

Comment: @PeterLillevold What's the difference between assigning a new instance to the `Instance` property (it's `get; set;`) and using `ReplaceInstance`? I can't seem to find any documentation on this.

Comment: @silkfire `ReplaceInstance` (via the `OnActivating` event) supersedes the `Instance` property. Thus, no there really is no difference to the end result. On old versions of Autofac you will have to use `Instance`, on newer versions you will have to use `ReplaceInstance`.

Comment: @silkfire I added a link to documentation on how to use the `ReplaceInstance`

Comment: @PeterLillevold Tack så mycket :)